# Should I disavow natural backlinks on forums?

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks, disavow-links

I was running backlinks analysis and it shown me some suspisious backlinks on forums. These links are natural, as users of these forums shared links with others.

Should I disavow such links in GWT?

Comment: If these backlinks are natural from users, keep them all. From Google, it's the golden rule for backlinks.

Comment: No need to remove them if they are relevant to your content and not spammy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep them if:
 - If they are normal urls (not with weird parameters)
 - The forum is of proper ranking (not spammy, decent reputation etc)
 - The forum is about the same general stuff as you have (eg: forum->cars & you->puppies = useless)

If it doesn't harm you, don't disgard. Backlinks have value in Google, but *quality over quantity*, but a backlink is a backlink. Maybe it's not the most optimal place to get linked from, but if users click the link and visit your site, who cares? You just got a visiter :)

PS: Bing! goes with the *quantity over quality* logic, so that will benefit.

Comment: If the backlinks are natural from users, they most probably come from a forum with the same theme (or a topic with the same theme at least).

Comment: Yes, most probably they are, but thats not guaranteed, hence me posting it. Apart from that, it's good general knowledge for other people :)

Comment: But what if one of the backlink analysis tools marks them as suspicious with a 50-70% chance that this is a toxic link, what do I do?

Comment: Do a manual check. Those are just tools, they're not perfect. Google's analysis will be WAY more advanced, just asume that if they're good, G will see the good.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to worry about those links if they are relevant or shared in the related place.

But, if you found any malicious or unnatural backlink then you need to remove them immediately.

To do this,

Step 1: Go to the disavow links tool page of Microsoft.

Step 2: Select your website.

Step 3: Click Disavow links.

Step 4: Click Choose file.

For more you can visit https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en

Comment: I think the general advice is to ask the other site to remove the links before resorting to the disavow tool